# Error: Unknown property 'Competitor.Competitor__c' Create Apex property 'Competitor.Competitor__c'

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

I have a custom object as Competitor__c , when an button "EDIT ALL "is clicked.i would like to get detail vf page record  displayed of that particular record linked to the custom object to edit  .I have created a Vf page but i do get Error as :

> Error: Unknown property 'Competitor.Competitor__c'  Create Apex
>   property 'Competitor.Competitor__c'   Create Apex method
>   'Competitor.getCompetitor__c'

Can any one help on this.

VF Code :

```
<apex:page controller="Competitor" sidebar="false" >
 <apex:form >
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Edit Competitors for" subtitle=""/>
  <apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton value="SAVE" action="{!SAVE}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="CANCEL" action="{!CANCEL}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="5">
       <apex:outputField value="{!Competitor__c.Part_Number__c}" label="PartNumber"/>
       <apex:outputField value="{!Competitor__c.Price_Offered__c}" label="Price">
       <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton" event="ondblclick"/> 
        </apex:outputField> 
        <apex:outputField value="{!Competitor__c.Volume__c}" label="Volume"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Competitor__c.Date_Price_is_valid__c}" label="Date Price is valid"/>    
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

  </apex:pageBlock>

 </apex:form>

  </apex:page>
```

Apex Class :

```
public with sharing class Competitor {

    public  Competitor__c com{get;set;}
   public  String CompetitorId{get;set;}

    public Competitor(){
    CompetitorId= System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Id');
    if(CompetitorId!= NULL){
    com =[Select id , Product_Series__c,Price_Offered__c,Part_Number__c,Date_Price_is_Valid__c ,Volume__c from Competitor__c where id =:CompetitorId];
    }
   }
         public PageReference SAVE() {
         try{
         upsert com;
         PageReference nextpage= new PageReference('/'+com.id);
           return nextpage;
      }
      catch(Exception e){
           // message='Data Base error during saving...';
           // ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message

//(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, message));
            return null;
        }
   }



    public PageReference CANCEL() {
        return null;
    }


   }
```

Comment: `com` is the name of the `Competitor__c`  variable that you declared in your controller so you should be referencing that variable in the page like `{!com.Part_Number__c}`

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you are referencing the wrong variable.

In your class you are initialising the "com" variable to hold the competitor record that you are retrieving based upon the Id from the standardController. In your VF page you need to reference this same variable like so below

```
<apex:page controller="Competitor" sidebar="false" >
  <apex:form >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Edit Competitors for" subtitle=""/>
    <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageBlockButtons >
         <apex:commandButton value="SAVE" action="{!SAVE}"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="CANCEL" action="{!CANCEL}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>
       <apex:pageBlockSection columns="5">
         <apex:outputField value="{!com.Part_Number__c}" label="PartNumber"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!com.Price_Offered__c}" label="Price">
           <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton" event="ondblclick"/> 
         </apex:outputField> 
         <apex:outputField value="{!com.Volume__c}" label="Volume"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!com.Date_Price_is_valid__c}" label="Date Price is valid"/>    
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
     </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I imagine you have looked through the documentation where it uses the Account standard controller and object example with {!account} as the binding hence the confusion.

As an aside you could probably use a standardcontroller here with your visualforce page to remove the need for the custom controller altogether.